# Running a single executable with sudo adds two processes in process list

Tags: sudo, ps

I wrote a program that captures the packets from the network interface. As it listens the network adapter, I need to run it with `sudo`. The question is, why when I run it, does it add two processes to the processes list?

*Note :  `lwdpi` is my program*

Before execution:

```
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/lwdpi_cpp$ ps ax | grep lwdpi
 4665 pts/21   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto lwdpi
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/lwdpi_cpp$ 

Execution:
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/lwdpi_cpp$ sudo ./lwdpi -i enp5s0
2016:10:26 11:07:29 ::   192.168.1.25   9918  -->     239.1.99.222   9918    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:29 ::  192.168.1.111   5353  -->      224.0.0.251   5353    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:30 ::  192.168.1.153   5353  -->      224.0.0.251   5353    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:30 ::  192.168.1.154   5353  -->      224.0.0.251   5353    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:30 ::   192.168.1.88   5353  -->      224.0.0.251   5353    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:30 ::   192.168.1.60   5353  -->      224.0.0.251   5353    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:37 ::  192.168.1.131  17500  -->  255.255.255.255  17500    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:37 ::  192.168.1.131  17500  -->    192.168.1.255  17500    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:37 ::  192.168.1.169   5546  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:37 ::  192.168.1.169  30955  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:38 ::  192.168.1.110  17500  -->  255.255.255.255  17500    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:38 ::  192.168.1.110  17500  -->    192.168.1.255  17500    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:42 ::  192.168.1.169  57189  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:42 ::  192.168.1.169  26072  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:42 ::  192.168.1.169  41674  -->   199.30.228.113     80    TCP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  41676  -->   199.30.228.113     80    TCP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169   7190  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  30029  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  41678  -->   199.30.228.113     80    TCP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  64975  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  12625  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  29973  -->     192.168.1.38     53    UDP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  53300  -->     216.58.211.4    443    TCP
2016:10:26 11:07:43 ::  192.168.1.169  41682  -->   199.30.228.113     80    TCP
.
.
.
```

Processes list while execution:

```
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/lwdpi_cpp$ ps ax | grep lwdpi
 4685 pts/22   S+     0:00 sudo ./lwdpi -i enp5s0
 4686 pts/22   S+     0:00 ./lwdpi -i enp5s0
 4691 pts/21   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto lwdpi
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/lwdpi_cpp$
```

As you see above, after execution, processes with PID = 4685 and PID = 4686 added to process list. Why? I didn't called my program inside it!

Comment: and when you do `sudo -i` insert your admin password and then do `./lwdpi -i enp5s0` you only get 1? ;-)

Comment: Yes! In cases I use `sudo -i` and then run the program, only one process adds to the processes list. but why?

Comment: so you get what I meant there? "sudo" is 1 process, your command the 2nd ;-) solution: dont use sudo. Use sudo -i to get a # then use your command.

Comment: Since `sudo` is also an executable, you're running two already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you do:

```
sudo ./lwdpi -i enp5s0
```

- `sudo` is the parent process, it `fork(2)`s a child, which then do `execve(2)` with `./lwdpi` as the executable name
- so `lwdpi` is `sudo`'s child process

This results in two processes as you can see, one is `sudo` and another is `lwdpi`.

The best way to see the details is to check the PPID (parent process ID) too:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,args | grep '[l]wdpi'
```

you'll see that `lwdpi`'s parent is `sudo` itself.

---

Here is `sudo`'s process model, from `man sudo`:

> When sudo runs a command, it calls fork(2), sets up the execution
>   environment as described above, and calls the execve system call in
>   the child process.  The main sudo process waits until the command has
>   completed, then passes the command's exit status
>        to the security policy's close function and exits.
>
> If an I/O logging plugin is configured or if the security policy explicitly
>   requests it, a new  pseudo-terminal (“pty”) is created and a second
>   sudo process is used to relay job control signals between
>        the user's existing pty and the new pty the command is being run in.  This extra process makes it possible to, for example, suspend and
>   resume the command.  Without it, the command would be in what POSIX
>   terms an “orphaned process group” and it would
>        not receive any job control signals.
>
> As a special case, if the policy plugin does not define a close function and no pty is required,
>   sudo will execute the command directly instead of calling fork(2)
>   first.  The sudoers policy plugin will only define a
>        close function when I/O logging is enabled, a pty is required, or the pam_session or pam_setcred options are enabled.  Note that
>   pam_session and pam_setcred are enabled by default on systems using
>   PAM.

Comment: A more detailed explanation of what sudo is doing with processes is in its man page: https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html#Process_model  . The reason why the sudo process keeps running until the command has finished is that sudo has to do additional work after the command finishes.

Answer (score 7):

This happens when you start any process with `sudo` One process is the `sudo` program and the other is the program launched with `sudo`, which is a child process of the first. The `sudo` program will exit only when the process it is running for (its child) exits. Here's an extract from my `pstree` when running `sudo apt update`

```
    ├─mate-terminal─┬
                    ├─bash───sudo───apt
               child of bash--^      ^--child of sudo
```